# I'm trying to map over objects, nested in objects that are nested in an array. What's the best way of tackling this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am receiving data from an API containing cryptocurrency market data. When a user searches for crypto the information of that crypto is fetched and added to the state. I would like to have each item that is returned from the API render to the user, slowly making a list of the data and sub-data.

I'm aware of mapping on an array, but cannot seem to get objects mapped (having attempted 'Object.key.map' too)

I have tried to target the items in the object, rather then the full objects returned themselves, but React doesn't seem to like me using uppercase in my code, with the dot notation of getting items from an object (uppercase appears to be required by the API as it returns data with uppercase:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
XTZ:
USD: 0.9505
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
1:
BTC:
USD: 9823.95
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
2:
ETH:
USD: 216.81
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

here are results from 3 returned query to the API.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cryptos: [],
      term: '',
      error: undefined
    };
  }


  getstuff = (symbol) => {
    axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${symbol}&tsyms=USD`)
    .then(res => {
      const crypto = res.data;
      console.log(crypto);
      if (res.data.Response === 'Error') {
        console.log('found error');
        const error = res.data.Message;
        if (error) {
          if (error.includes('toSymbol/s')){
            this.setState({error: `We cannot find ${symbol} in our list of cryptos. Please ensure you're using the symbol, not the full name (ie 'BTC', not 'Bitcoin')`})
            console.log(this.state);
          } else {
            this.setState({error: `Hmmmm, we're run into an error, and frankly have no idea what it is.`})
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.setState({ cryptos: [...this.state.cryptos, crypto] });

      }
    })
  }

  onInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({ term: e.target.value});
  }

  onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.getstuff(this.state.term.toUpperCase());
    this.setState({term: ''})
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <div className="field">
            <label>Video Search</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.term}
              onChange={this.onInputChange}/>

          </div>
        </form>
        {`you searched ${this.state.term}`}
        {this.state.cryptos.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>item</li>)}
        {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
        <button onClick={() =>  {console.log(this.state.cryptos)}}> console log current state </button>
      </div>
      )

    }
  }
```

I'm trying to extract and render the cryptocurrency name that is returned (should match user query), as well as the price (in USD) that is returned with it.

ideally along the lines of

Selection 1: BTC, $9452 at the time of the query.

Selection 2: ETH, $202 at the time of the query.

Selection 3: XTZ, $0.92 at the time of the query.

Comment: I'm trying to understand where the problem is... you want to show name on line wich says {this.state.cryptos.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>item</li>)}? Is there any error being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

If i have an object like this:

```
obj = [
  { name: "Jon", ID: { num: 23, country: "Canada" } },
  { name: "Mary", ID: { num: 28, country: "Russia" } },
  { name: "Jon2", ID: { num: 12, country: "Germany" } }
];
```

I would iterate like so:

```
obj.map(element => { Object.keys(element).map( key => console.log(element[key]))})
```

Answer (score 0):

request `?fsyms=EUR,GBP&tsyms=USD`
gives me:

```
{
  "EUR":{ "USD":1.124 },
  "GBP":{ "USD":0.03747 }
}
```

I would iterate it like this:

```
const data = {
  "EUR":{ "USD":1.124 },
  "UAH":{ "USD":0.03747 }
};
Object.keys(data).forEach((key, i) => {
  console.log(`Selection ${i}: ${key}, $${data[key]["USD"]} at time of query.`);
});
```

If you add more matches to the internal object, then you can iterate like this:

```
const data = {
  "EUR":{ "USD":1.124, "GBP":0.8991 },
  "UAH":{ "USD":0.03747, "GBP":0.03016 }
};
let i = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  const values = data[key];
  Object.keys(values).forEach(key2 => {
    console.log(`Selection ${++i}: ${key}, ${key2} is $${data[key][key2]}.`);
  });
});
```

Which will result in:
Selection 1: EUR, USD is $1.124.
Selection 2: EUR, GBP is $0.8991.
Selection 3: UAH, USD is $0.03747.
Selection 4: UAH, GBP is $0.03016.